# Services section of Azure YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm looking at an [example of the YAML pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#single-container-job) with a `services` section. Here is a sample:

[image]

[The YAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/?view=azure-pipelines) doesn't have services defined.

Where can I get information about the `services` section of the pipeline?

**Update:** Per Bowman's answer, the `services` section is part of the `job` step. In this scenario, there is only one job so the `job` step is omitted.

> In the simplest case, a pipeline has a single job. In that case, you do not have to explicitly use the job keyword unless you are using a template. You can directly specify the steps in your YAML file.
> [here is the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#define-a-single-job)

Comment: There is, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in the official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines

> services:  # Container resources to run as a service container.

I think you directly check it in the top level, right? In fact, in this situation, there is a hidden default job, the definition of the job also be hidden. services section is under the job definition of that hidden job, not the top level.

Comment: Didn't know about the hidden job. Updated my answer with more details. Thanks!